# Php/Mysqli error with insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, web

I'm trying to rebuild my php/mysql website with mysqli methods. I would to insert a new record in my table SEZIONE, it attributes are:

```
ID_STAGIONE number (primary key),
ORDINE number,
TITOLO varchar(100),
PUBBLICO varchar(1)
```

I build dinamically my query, and after i execute it with this istruction:

```
$db->query($query);
```

It doesn't work. I decided to print the value of the variable $query, and it is perfect:

```
insert into SEZIONE (ID_STAGIONE, ORDINE, TITOLO, PUBBLICO) values ('2', '20', 'prova', 'S')
```

If I execute the query in phpmyadmin sql terminal.. it work! I know that the fields ID_STAGIONE and ORDINE are numbers, so it's not necessary the character **'**, but it work in phpmyadmin sql terminal.
There's anyone that can help me?!?

Comment: Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Yes, I found other errors and I saw them

Comment: ID_STAGIONE should be Integer. try to put  `$db->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: Its should work on phpMyAdmin . That why i give u mysqli_error code to check what the problem with query. Check updated code

Comment: it return

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Its comes after my code or before?

Comment: after that i put yout code

Comment: ID_STAGIONE is primary key. Primary keys must contain unique values.

Comment: sorry here there's my error when i writed the question.. ID_STAGIONE is not primary key but foreign key, the table is SEZIONE and its primary key is ID_SEZIONE (number)...

Comment: It's really strange:

 echo $query;
 $db->query($query);

In this moment the variable $query is:

insert into SEZIONE (ID_STAGIONE, ORDINE, TITOLO, PUBBLICO) values ('2', '10', 'Prova', 'S')

and it doesn't work. After I build manally my query and it work!

 $query = "insert into SEZIONE (ID_STAGIONE, ORDINE, TITOLO, PUBBLICO) values ('2', '10', 'Prova', 'S')";
 $db->query($query);

I found the record in the table, but not with $db->query($query);

Comment: Than use this Here is my code

    `$query = "insert into SEZIONE (ID_STAGIONE, ORDINE, TITOLO, PUBBLICO) values ('2', '20', 'prova', 'S')";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));

$conn == database connecteda`

Comment: @Rajlaksh The reply at my code

 echo $q . "<br>";
 $result = $db->query($q) or die("Errore: ". mysqli_error($db));

is:

insert into `SEZIONE` (`ID_STAGIONE`, `ORDINE`, `TITOLO`, `PUBBLICO`) values (`2`, `40`, `Ciao`, `S`)
Errore: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: change number with integer maybe that will fix it. invalid data is here `ID_STAGIONE number (primary key),
ORDINE number,`   change number with integer. Number does not exists in mysql